# Practical Minimal Cost of Living in Canada for a Single Indian person (Male)

Tags: canada, cost-of-living, ontario

I have couple of questions regarding the Cost Of living in Canada (Ontario Region). Please kindly note that, maximum cost saving is required in all possible ways. I can live without leisure life. Only basic need including Internet & Mobile bills for living can alone be applied.

1. I would like to know if a Single Person from India can live in Canada under the budget of ~c$800 per month if Sharing Accommodation is opted-for living?
2. How common is it for People to get Sharing Accommodation there?
3. If not, how much a person can save to the maximum per year if one gets c$80,000 salaried job there ***after deducting all Taxes, Monthly Rentals for Room, Mobile charges, Internet, Food, transportation etc***.

The intention here is to save maximum money per year and send back to home. I was looking for saving a minimum of c$49,430 per year.

Is it possible to save that much in a year in anyways? If someone can help me with this in any combination of cost saving budget plans, it would be really really helpful.

If self cooking is an option, then I can learn cooking also if required.

**UPDATE 1:**
I was informed that only about $500 to $700 is all required to spend per month on total if Sharing accommodation is opted for living without any transportation as the office is in walk-able distance.
Is it possible to save ~$49k per year?

Comment: How have you arrived at the figure of $1,400pm for living expenses? https://www.wealthsimple.com/en-ca/tool/tax-calculator/ Have you looked at cost of living comparison sites eg https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living/quebec-city? Learning to cook would be essential in this scenario, I’d imagine

Comment: @Traveller, I kind of came up with that value of $1,400 in reverse order. First I subtracted the taxes as per my knowledge of $13,703.9 per year. Which leaves me at $66,296.1 per year i.e. $5,524.675 per month. I was informed by my superiors that I could save about $24,714 per six months i.e $4119 per month. So, the remaining amount left to spend is ($5,524.675 - $4119) = ~$1,405.6. This is how i came up with value "1,400". So, this is what puzzled me to know if this is possible or not.  They are saying for sure, I can save about $24,714 per six months if spent wisely.

Comment: @Unknown where did your number for taxes come from? The tax calculator Traveller linked seems to say you’d be left with 59k after tax. That leaves much less than 1.4k per month available for living costs if you want to save 49k per year. More like 800 dollars per month, if the site is accurate.

Comment: @ChrisH , Yeah.. I checked the Tax Calculator provided by Traveller. The tax amount I quoted is the one I manually calculated based on Canadian Tax Slabs i.e 15% for 1st slab of ~$49K and 20.5% for 2nd slab ~$49K. Here my calculations can be wrong too.. i updated my Question with more info under "Update "Section

Comment: @Unknown those are the federal income tax brackets. There are also provincial taxes and other expenses such as employment insurance and pension contributions to account for if you want to work out what your net income would be. The site Traveller linked is for the 2020 tax year, so might not be exactly right if some of there have been changes to tax brackets or other expenses, etc., but it will be much more realistic than what you've calculated.

Comment: Also, your first comment says that your superiors told you you could save "about $24,714 per six months" - while they probably have an interest in convincing you to accept the offer, they're also far better placed than we are to estimate the cost of housing within walking distance of the office. I doubt we can really help you a whole lot. If their $500-$700 p/m number is realistic, then $80k probably (just about) leaves you with enough for your goal - unless you run into unexpected expenses. I'd very much advise saving at least 2-3 months' salary for *yourself* to account for that possibility.

Comment: I'm also a bit unclear what your actual requirements are. Over the course of a year, that "$24,714 per six months" works out to be almost exactly the $49,430 per year that you say is your minimum savings goal. Did you just double the number you were told was possible in six months, or is that (oddly specific) number genuinely a "minimum" for some reason? In other words, would saving $45k or $40k per year be unacceptable? Most people would still consider that an extremely large amount to be able to save in one year.

Comment: @ChrisH, First of all.. Thank you for you kind responses which gave some insights to me. Actually I was looking for a better Job change, and my current employer convinced me to send on-site by saying that I could save $24,714 per six months. So, I simply doubled the amount which they quoted to me. I was little doubtful about it. Hence thought of clarifying the same with open community members here.. :)

Comment: I think you should ask Q2 as a separate question, giving more information about the background to your request eg the precise location(s) you’d be interested in, projected arrival date, intended length of stay. The rest of your question is really asking for opinions, IMHO it’s unlikely you’ll get an answer to it in its current form. Perhaps if you put together your own indicative budget from your research someone with local knowledge might be able to respond.